# How to run sass on ssh server?

Tags: html, css, ruby, ssh, sass

I use sass in my home and office, i am working on Windows. Everything work without any issue. Problem start when i want start using sass in my home via ssh. How can i use sass to files on ssh serwer?
When i am working with sass on my local files everything working good, but when i log in to ssh via git bash and start typin

```
sass --watch style_scss:style_css
```

i see

```
-bash: sass comand not found
```

And what i figure out when i type some ruby comand I also see `-bash: ruby comand not found`. Both this command work when i am not on my ssh serwer. What i can do to run sass throught ssh?

Comment: In order to use it, you have to install `sass` on the machine. (same for Ruby)

Comment: I have sass and ruby on my machine. I used it many times. When i log in to my ssh server from my machine, sass and ruby not working (node.js is working). How can I run sass via ssh?

Comment: When you log in to your server, you are not on your machine anymore. You therefore have to install the tool on your server, too.

Comment: Ok, thank U for this prompt. So the question is how can I install it on my server? When i use ' sudo apt-get install ruby-full' and write the password I see 'User is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.' Can I add myself to sudoers file or must do it someone in my company?

Comment: Seems like you don't have the permissions to do so.

Answer (score 1):

That error message means sass isn't installed on your linuxserver!
Also ruby isn't installed.

If you are using ubuntu/debian use the following commands.
Ruby: `sudo apt-get install ruby-full`
Sass: `npm install -g sass` ( Requires nodejs to be installed )

For other distro's google the commands!

Comment: You seem to be missing the correct command for Sass.

Comment: woops! i fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

When joining via ssh run this command in the console to verify you have ruby and sass installed in the computer you're reaching.

`sass --version`

`ruby -v`

if these commands don't output the version of both ruby and sass, you're going to have to install them.

Can you elaborate on the process on how you connect via ssh?